# How to detect the latest spam emails

Tags: email, spoofing, email-filter

I am being inundated with annoying messages from "women" who all share the similar email address format i.e "susie_skank@susie_skank.x, y or z".. Cannot see how to filter these pests. I have MailWasher.

Comment: Wouldn't that rather fit into SuperUser?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the software, but from what I have found you are able to input a regular expression as a filter to emails. If you use (\w+_\w+)@$1.\w{1,3} as a filter, it should take care of your problem. :) However, if it does not, Mailwasher's regular expression engine may not support capturing, in that case replace $1 with \1, Best of luck! :D